# Assembly 'MathNet.Numerics' with identity "MathNet.Numerics' Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=###' uses 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0

Tags: c#, mathnet-numerics

I'm using tickblaze, a software package that runs C# scripts for algorithmic trading. I want to run a strategy that uses linear algebra, so I need MathNet.Numerics package.  I referenced MathNet.Numberics, but and I was getting the following errors:

> The type 'double' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type of method 'Matrix'.  There is no boxing conversion from 'double' to 'System.IEquatable.'.
> The type 'double' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type of method 'Matrix'.  There is no boxing conversion from 'double' to 'System.IFormattable'.
> The type 'double' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type of method 'Matrix'.  There is no boxing conversion from 'double' to 'System.ValueType'.
> The type 'IEquatable<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.  You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
> The type 'IFormattable<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.  You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
> The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.  You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
> The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.  You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

Then, I referenced the System.Runtime File in .NET files (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319), and now I have the following error(s):

> Assembly 'MathNet.Numerics' with identity "MathNet.Numerics' Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=###' uses 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=###'

Can anyone tell what I am missing?

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post a [mre].

Comment: the exception tells you to add a reference v6.0.0.0 - what makes you feel, that v4.0.x will do the job?